# Boost Graph Library A* for consistent heuristic

Tags: boost, a-star, boost-graph

I've read that, when applying A* to a problem, if your heuristic is consistent then you can further optimize the A* search. The Boost Graph Library offers two versions of the A* algorithm: `astar_search` and `astar_search_tree`. The documentation isn't very clear on the distinction between the two; does one of these perform the optimized search which assumes a consistent heuristic?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I got the answer I was looking for by consulting the Boost mailing list. I'll reproduce the answer here for posterity:

> The distinction is whether there should be an effort made to avoid 
>   visiting the same vertex multiple times. For a graph where vertices can 
>   often by reached using many paths, you should prefer astar_search to avoid 
>   extra work from revisiting that vertex and its successors. If it is 
>   unlikely that the same vertex will appear on multiple paths, or checking 
>   vertices is inexpensive enough that it is not worthwhile to avoid repeated 
>   work, use astar_search_tree which does not remember which vertices it has 
>   visited previously. The disadvantage of trying to find repeated vertices 
>   is that it requires a growing amount of memory to store the lookup table 
>   of which vertices have been seen before, and it takes time to search and 
>   update this table. Both versions of the algorithm require admissible 
>   heuristics to work correctly.

[Link to the thread](http://lists.boost.org/boost-users/2013/04/78681.php)

Answer (score -1):

The difference between the `_tree` and the non `_tree` boost graph algorithm versions is that the `_tree` version assumes your graph is really a tree, so it has no cycles and only has one in arrow for node.

Comment: I don't think this is true; I have an undirected graph with cycles and astar_search_tree still works just fine.

Comment: Playing with fire! "If a dummy value is used for the distance map and the graph contains cycles, the algorithm will probably enter an infinite loop" (http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/graph/doc/astar_search.html). If your graph isn't a tree you *should not* use the _tree versions.

Comment: @giogadi: That does not mean it will work on all non-tree graphs.  http://codinghorror.typepad.com/.a/6a0120a85dcdae970b0128776ff992970c-pi

Comment: Thanks for the input, but as for the documentation that Roberto is citing, I read it as "if the graph has cycles AND a dummy value is used for the distance map", not to use the _tree version. The documentation is vague here, as I said before. I.e., if I specify a non-dummy distance map is it ok to use the _tree version?

Comment: @giogadi: for the _tree version the algorithm assumes each node visited hasn't been visited before "all vertices are assumed to always be white..." (in the same paragraph). So you may enter an infinite loop, even if your distance map isn't a dummy value.

Comment: @Roberto: Sorry to keep this going, but in that very same sentence it says "...leading to checking for REPEATED vertices being done using the distance map", meaning repeat vertices are indeed checked, except the distance map is used for this, not the open/closed structure. This looks to me like the optimization used for consistent heuristics, but I'm not certain.

Comment: @giogardi: Well, the pseudocode explains it more clearly, if each vertex is always white no test is made to check if it has been visited before. I would like you to check the algorithm behavior when your graph is a ring: G = <{a,b,c} ; {[a -> b], [b -> c], [c -> a]}>.

Comment: I've tried astar_search_tree with all sorts of circular graphs and graphs with cycles, all sorts of heuristics, and all sorts of costs, and I still haven't run into any errors or infinite loops. Obviously this isn't real proof, but we should consider other possibilities for the distinction between the two functions.

Comment: I'll check that at the weekend :)